# 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error' message driving me nuts

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my code. Can anyone tell me what or where it is incorrect, please?  I've spent over 3 days trying to figure it out and not seeing it and my report is due next week.

```
SELECT
   t1.IT1 as "Issue Type",
   t1.sum(REC) as "Total Received",
   t2.sum(RES) as "Total Resolved",
   t1.Count(project_key) as REC,
   t2.Count(project_key) as RES
FROM
   (select
    IT1 as "Issue Type",
    sum(REC) as "Total Received"
    FROM
       (case
        when issue_type = 'MIS Sub-task' then 'MIS'
        when issue_type = 'Reporting Sub-task' then 'Reporting'
        when issue_type = 'NICE Analytics Sub-task' then 'NICE Analytics'
        when issue_type = 'Demand Mitigation Sub-task' then 'Demand Mitigation'
        else issue_type
        end as IT1,
Count(project_key) as REC
FROM jira17.FCI4JIRA_common_view 
WHERE issue_type in ('MIS', 'MIS Sub-task', 'Reporting', 'Reporting Sub-Task', 'NICE Analytics', 'NICE Analytics Sub-Task', 'Demand Mitigation', 'Demand Mitigation Sub-Task') and 
status not like 'Cancelled' and 
date_created between to_date ('01/12/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date ('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') group by issue_type)  group by IT1) t1

inner join t2 on t1.IT1 = t2.IT2

  (select 
    IT2 as "Issue Type",
    sum(RES) as "Total Resolved"
    FROM
       (case
        when issue_type = 'MIS Sub-task' then 'MIS'
        when issue_type = 'Reporting Sub-task' then 'Reporting'
        when issue_type = 'NICE Analytics Sub-task' then 'NICE Analytics'
        when issue_type = 'Demand Mitigation Sub-task' then 'Demand Mitigation'
        else issue_type
        end as IT2,
Count(project_key) as RES
from jira17.FCI4JIRA_common_view 
where issue_type in ('MIS', 'MIS Sub-task', 'Reporting', 'Reporting Sub-Task', 'NICE Analytics', 'NICE Analytics Sub-Task', 'Demand Mitigation', 'Demand Mitigation Sub-Task') and 
status not like 'Cancelled' and 
date_resolved between to_date ('01/12/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date ('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') group by issue_type) group by IT2) t2
```

Comment: Line 11 and 12. Syntax error on `FROM
       (case` -> `select` missing.

Comment: @danhip you found it. make it an answer

Comment: Thanks, had it that way before which gave me ORA-00936: missing expression. Any and all help appreciated.  I've read through it so many times it's beginning to look like a blur. LOL

Comment: `t1.sum(REC)` should be `sum(t1.REC)`, etc. as well. That might be your ORA-00936 error. But you also have a disconnect before the `(select IT2...`. Showing which line an error is reported against would help. You should really break this down into smaller chunks that work and then put them back together carefully.

Comment: @Bohemian, I have tried to post the a decent answer.

Comment: Using the latest versions of SQL Clients like SQL Developer or Toad might help you get rid of most of the syntax errors right when you write the query.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very complex SQL sentence. Because this, your question is unreadable. Community can not spend time to debug your query. You should be able to do it for yourself. I suggest to you "divide and rule" because this, you should learn about CTE expressions. With CTE you organize your query in a more readable way.

For your sentence:

```
With T11 as (
 select
      case
            when issue_type = 'MIS Sub-task' then 'MIS'
            when issue_type = 'Reporting Sub-task' then 'Reporting'
            when issue_type = 'NICE Analytics Sub-task' then 'NICE Analytics'
            when issue_type = 'Dema...gation Sub-task' then 'Demand Mitigation'
            else issue_type
            end as IT1,
      Count(project_key) as REC
 FROM 
      jira17.FCI4JIRA_common_view 
 WHERE issue_type in ('MIS', 'MIS Sub-task', 'Reporting', ...) and 
          status not like 'Cancelled' and 
          date_created between to_date ('01/12/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
          and to_date ('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
 GROUP BY issue_type ),
T1 as (
 SELECT
    t1.IT1 as "Issue Type",
    t1.sum(REC) as "Total Received",
    t2.sum(RES) as "Total Resolved",
    t1.Count(project_key) as REC,
    t2.Count(project_key) as RES
FROM
    FROM T11
    group by IT1 ),
-- and so on ...
```

["How to use SQL Server CTEs to make your T-SQL code readable by humans"](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2975/how-to-use-sql-server-ctes-to-make-your-tsql-code-readable-by-humans/) is a post for T-SQL but you can learn from it.

Comment: Sorry.  Thanks for the link.  Will definitely give it a read and hopefully be able to revamp this.

Comment: I haven't had time to get into CTE's so let me revamp my question to see if it would be of any help.  Can anyone tell me how I would join these 2 queries which both work individually....

Comment: on second thought, nm.  Thanks for your time